# substitute a line in an excel file from perl using system call

Tags: excel, perl, sed

I need to replace a line in an excel file from a perl script. This line contains multiple columns each column is separated by tab.
I've tried:

```
$data="v1\tv2\tv2";
$data_replace="c1\tc2\t\c3";
$ret = system("sed -i \"s/$data/$data_replace/g\" file.xls");
print $ret; #256
```

Also tried, but doesn't work:

```
$ret = system("sed -i \"s/\"$data/\"$data_replace\"/g\" file.xls");
$ret = system("sed -i \"s/'$data'/'$data_replace'/g\" file.xls");
```

However if I do this, it works:

```
$ret = system("sed -i \"s/aaa/bbb/g\" file.xls");
```

Why it doesn't work when I want to substitute the $data variable?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you call sed from within perl with all the variable interpolation pitfalls such a thing imposes to use a command that not only exists in perl directly but even has the same syntax?

Comment: Also: try `${data}` and `${data_replaced}`. This will ensure that perl understands what is part of the variable name and what is not. But it still should have replaced the pattern with something, i think.

Comment: It turns out: Your first syntax does work for me like a charm. Are you sure there are actually tabs in that file and not emulated ones as many editors use them? Like if you open the file with an editor (not excel) do you see those tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my data variable `$data="v1\tv2\tv2";, if v1, v2 are "/" (data contains "/")`, this character is not recognized by sed, so I used:
`$ret = system("sed -i \"s#$data#$data_replace#g\" file.xls");`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# prepare a \t catch in buffer \(\t\)
$data="v1\(\t\)v2\tv2";
# use catch tab \1 instead of tab
$data_replace="c1\1c2\1\c3";
$ret = system("sed -i \"s/$data/$data_replace/g\" file.xls");
print $ret; #256
```

the \t in second sed pattern is not always "understand" as tab, so a workaround is to use a tab catch in a buffer from first pattern the `\(\t\)` where it is understand an to use it in second one as `\1` in this case